# Jenkins user permissions issue (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, github, permissions, continuous-integration

I'm getting a "Permission denied (publickey)" error whenever I try to run a simple Jenkinsfile from Github which does an "ls" on a remote server.

I'm new to linux and ci/cd in general but I believe that this has to do with a user permissions error as the directory which runs the build (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myrepo) has jenkins:jenkins as the owner whereas i'm logged in as ubuntu.

I tried to change the $JENKINS_USER in /etc/defaults/jenkins but this ends up making my jenkins site unavailable.

How can I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: From the error, you are unable to ssh to the remote server. The default user that runs jenkins is **jenkins**. Check if you are able to ssh to the remote server from jenkins user.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue by installing the ssh agent plugin and including its ID in my jenkinsfile.

```
stage ('Deploy') {
            steps{
                sshagent(credentials : ['credentials-ID-here']) {
                    sh 'your command here'
                }
            }
        }
```